# Get symlink "as is" in Python?

Tags: python

Give

```
$ ll ./
$ foo1
$ foo2 -> /absolute/path/to/bar2
$ foo3 -> bar3
```

I know

```
os.path.islink()
```

tells me if a file is a symlink.

I also know

```
os.path.realpath()
```

gives me the real, absolute path of a symlink. I have no problems with it returning me `/absolute/path/to/bar2` for `os.path.realpath('foo2')`.

But for `os.path.realpath('foo3')`, I want `bar3` ("as is" in the title).

Is there a simpler way than computing `relpath` with `foo3`'s directory as start?

Comment: [os.readlink](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.readlink) appears to do what you want.

Comment: ^ And there's your answer.

Comment: @0x5453 Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @alex Done.  [extra words for comment length requirement]

Answer (score 1):

[os.readlink](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.readlink) appears to do what you want.